# Infinite number of students

Tags: probability

Consider countably infinite number of students. They all sit on an infinite line.
They all try to solve a problem. The probability of the event "student $N$ solves the problem" is $0.5$ $\forall N$. Every student can cheat and write off the correct solution from left or right neighbour. The probability of successful cheating is $0.25$.

Question: what is the probability of a fixed student to gain a correct solution to the problem?

My answer is $\frac{2}{3}$ but something tells me this is wrong.

Comment: This could use a bit of clarification.  Presumably each student who can't solve the problem can recognize when a neighbour has the answer, whether obtained fairly or by copying from that student's other neighbour.  In that case the student will try to copy, and have probability $1/4$ of succeeding.  But what if both neighbours have the answer and the first attempt to copy is unsuccessful?  Does the student try to copy from the other neighbour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a student can only try to copy from one neighbour: $p$ is the probability of a single student finding the solution, and $q$ is the probability of a student finding the solution given that one of his neighbours does not (at least not before he does). Equations for $p$ and $q$ are
$$p=0.5+(1-0.5)\cdot \Big(1-(1-q)^2\Big)\cdot0.25,$$
and
$$q=0.5+(1-0.5)\cdot q\cdot0.25.$$
This should be interpreted as follows: The student finds the solution himself with probability $0.5$. If he fails that (with probability $1-0.5$), he will look at his neighbours. Since he has at this point not solved the problem, his neighbours will have solved it with probability $q$. The probability that a given neighbour fails is $1-q$, so the probability that both neighbours fail is $(1-q)^2$. Thus the probability that at least one of our students neigbours finds the solution is $1-(1-q)^2$. If a neigbour finds the answer, then our student can successfully copy this answer with probability $0.25$.

The calculation for $q$ is similar, but here there is only one neigbour that can find the answer (if our student is looking at the neighbour on the right, then the neighbour won't find the answer on his left).

These equations gives $q=\frac47$ and $p=\frac{59}{98}\approx0.602$.

---

If a student can try to copy from one neighbour if he fails to copy from the other, we get a different equation for $p$:
$$p=0.5+(1-0.5)\cdot\Bigg(2\cdot q\cdot(1-q)\cdot0.25+q^2\cdot\bigg(1-(1-0.25)^2\bigg)\Bigg)$$
The change can be explained as follows: If the student fails by himself there are two possibilities where the student can try to cheat: either exactly one of his neighbours succeed, or both do. The probability of exacly one neighbour succeeding is $2\cdot q\cdot(1-q)$ (left neighbour succeeding and right neighbour failing plus vice versa). In that case he can try to copy once and succeeds with probability $0.25$. The probability of both neighbours succeding is $q^2$, and in this case the student can manage to cheat with probability $1-(1-0.25)^2$.

The equation for $q$ doesn't change, so in this case we get $p=\frac{62}{98}\approx0.633$.

Comment: Conditioned on at least one of the neighbors finds the solution, the probability to successfully get the answer from them is not $0.25$: it is $0.25$ conditioned on exactly one of them having the solution, and $1-0.75^2=0.4375$ if both have it.

Comment: I assumed in my answer that if a student finds an answer on either side, he can try to copy that answer, but there is a 75% chance that he will get caught and immediately fail the test. I found that scenario more likely than getting two attempts to cheat.

Comment: The other interpretation is also possible: when trying to cheat from one student there is a 75% risk that he will notice and cover his answers. In that case you can still try the other side. I will add that case to the answer :)

Comment: I agree that the OP's question is a bit... fuzzy. Both interpretations make sense, but one has to specify which one is considered :)